# git filter in on premise TFS 2015 Update 3

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

If the repository is git behind our TFS project there is no way to filter the repository by source folder. The build always pull the whole repository. We have multiple solutions in the TFS project we want to build separetly. We can do it, but it is slow because we cannot filter the source folder to download.

The other problem that we cannot add folder to CI trigger. So all the projects will be build after a push in any projects.

I know that the Team Services already support path filters for git repository. But does anybody know some workarounds for this problem for on premise TFS 2015 Update 3?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no workaround for this on TFS 2015 update3.** Unless separate your components into different repositories. Multiple projects must be in their own repository. All dependencies is a project by it self and can be handled as NuGet packages. Then your whole solution would not break if you change something in the dependency project and using CI trigger.

> This feature will ship in **TFS 15** and is already available on VSTS
>
> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/news/2016#june-14